# java web app write file to specific location

Tags: java, weblogic

In java controller of Spring web app, I create a report and write it to AuditReport.html.  The write works ok and when I search for the file, I find it in `/home/emm/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/AuditReport.html`.

I want to write it to some place that I will be able to download it with a download link.

In Eclipse I modify the weblogic.xml file so it contains a Virtual Directory Mapping entry.  Local path is set to "/app/config".  In that folder I created "download" folder. I add URL Pattern of /download/* to we

In the jsp file I have link like this

```
<a href="download/AuditReport.html" download>Export Report</a>
```

When I click it in Chrome I see it trying to download it but then says "Failed - No file"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have your tried to remove `download` from the `<a>` to see whether this directory is accessible or even found?

Comment: Yes.  Same error.

Comment: what are the settings for 
<virtual-directory-mapping>
     <local-path>
     <url-pattern>
     <url-pattern>

Answer (score 0):

you mention the file is getting generated at /home/emm/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/AuditReport.html

where are you mapping /home/emm/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/  to your virtual directory ?